# Parsing an XML with namespaces using F# XMLProvider

Tags: xml, f#, xml-namespaces, type-providers

I've been trying to parse an XML NLog message using XMLProvider.
In my project I defined the provider in the following way:

```xml
XmlProvider<"""
    <log4j:event 
        logger="MyTest" level="INFO" timestamp="1597329370954" thread="1">
        <log4j:message>
            Running task
        </log4j:message>
        <log4j:locationInfo class="My.Task" method="Void main(System.String[])" />
        <nlog:eventSequenceNumber>
            11
        </nlog:eventSequenceNumber>
        <nlog:locationInfo assembly="My.Task, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
        <nlog:properties />
        <log4j:properties>
            <data name="log4japp" value="My.Task(64400)" />
            <data name="log4jmachinename" value="BNT" />
        </log4j:properties>
    </log4j:event>""">
```

But this doesn't compile, as I get exceptions about missing namespace definitions.
So I added xmlns to the root element, making it:

```xml
XmlProvider<"""
    <log4j:event 
        xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/"
        xmlns:nlog="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
        logger="MyTest" level="INFO" timestamp="1597329370954" thread="1">
        <log4j:message>
           ...
        ...
    </log4j:event>""">
```

And it helps my project to compile, but it throws an exception at runtime while attempting to parse an XML:

```
    'log4j' is an undeclared prefix. Line 1, position 2.
```

I got away with the problem by preprocessing the xml and removing all the xml namespaces from all the tags. While this works, I wonder if there's a better solution.

Comment: It works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works fine for me, but you need to include the XML namespace declarations in both the sample XML and also in the actual data. For example, the following works fine:

```
// Simplified declaration with namespaces included
type X = XmlProvider<"""
  <log4j:event xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/"
        xmlns:nlog="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd">
      <log4j:message>Running task</log4j:message>
      <nlog:eventSequenceNumber>11</nlog:eventSequenceNumber>
  </log4j:event>""">

// Load a sample data file with namespaces included
let x = X.Parse("""
<log4j:event xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/"
      xmlns:nlog="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd">
    <log4j:message>Running task</log4j:message>
    <nlog:eventSequenceNumber>11</nlog:eventSequenceNumber>
</log4j:event>""")

// Returns the data from the XML just fine!
x.Message
x.EventSequenceNumber
```

If you omit the XML namespace declarations from the data, this fails:

```
let y = X.Parse("""
<log4j:event>
    <log4j:message>Running task</log4j:message>
    <nlog:eventSequenceNumber>11</nlog:eventSequenceNumber>
</log4j:event>""")
```

I don't think there is a way to tell the XML type provider to implicitly include namespace declarations - I can see how this would be a useful feature, so feel free to make a suggestion on the project GitHub!

Comment: On and off this has always been a sporadic bump in the road since .... at least 15-20 years - from XmlDocument stuff in the VB6 era over various xml technologies (in .NET etc). It should be easy but those schema caches and whatnot which often had to be set up in the past made it tedious. And all that while I wondered, whether or not it is possible without losing correctness if an xml implementation simply says: "there is a namespace prefix - so there is a namespace - but I don't care what that namespace defines exactly." Given that document validation usually was an extra step anyway.

Comment: @Tomas, thanks - this is exactly the case, as my pieces of XML that I attempt to parse do indeed miss namespace definitions. Thanks for confirming there's no easy walkaround to that.